# Нужна помощь по коду Java. Статические классы, объекты и методы, код не желает запускаться, не знаю в чем причина

Tags: java, классы

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class MathFun {
    static int sthow;
    static MathFun() {
        
    }
    public static float Mean(float x){
        return x;

    }
    public static float cos(float x){
        float y = Math.cos(x);
        return y;
    }
    public static float tg(float x){
        float y = Math.tan(x);
        return y;
    }
    public static float ctg(float x){
        float y = Math.cos(x)/Math.sin(x);
        return y;
    }
    public static float Sqrt(float x){
        float y = Math.sqrt(x);
        return y;
    }
    public static int Round(float x){
        int y = Math.round(x);
        return y;
    }
    public static float Upsidedown(float x){
        float y = 0-x;
        return y;
    }
    public static float NotInt(float x){
        int y = Math.round(x);
        float v = x-y;
        return v;
    }
    public static int Int(float x){
        int y = Math.round(x);
        float v = x-y;
        int d = x-v;
        return d;
    }
    public static boolean WhatParity(float a){
        if (a%2==0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static float Factorial(int x){
        int f = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <=x; i ++){
            f = f*i;
        }
        return f;
    }   
    public static float NSD(float x, float y){
        if (x == 0){
            return y;
        }

        while (y != 0) {
            if (x > y){
                x = x - y;
            }
            else{
                y = y - x;
        }
        return x;
    }
}  
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathFun v = new MathFun();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("print x");
        float x = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("print x");
        float y = in.nextFloat();
        float s = v.Mean(x);
        System.out.println("x="+s);
        float a = v.cos(x);
        System.out.println("cos x="+a);
        float q = v.tg(x);
        System.out.println("tg x="+q);
        float w = v.ctg(x);
        System.out.println("ctg x="+w);
        float e = v.Sqrt(x);
        System.out.println("sqrt x="+e);
        int r = v.Round(x);
        System.out.println("round x="+r);
        float t = v.Upsidedown(x);
        System.out.println("not x="+t);
        float k = v.NotInt(x);
        System.out.println("not int x="+k);
        int u = v.Int(x);
        System.out.println("int x="+u);
        boolean i = v.WhatParity(x);
        System.out.println("parity x="+i);
        float o = v.Factorial(x);
        System.out.println("factorial x="+o);
        float p = v.NSD(x, y);
        System.out.println("NSD x&y="+p);
    }
}
```

выдает такую ошибку:
Main.java:110: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
^
1 error
помогите пожалуйста, уже даже не знаю что делать

Comment: Не понимаю зачем ради этого задавать вопрос? Ошибка же написана! А так в функции `NSD` не хватает `}` после `y = y - x`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathFun v = new MathFun();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("print x");
        float x = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("print x");
        float y = in.nextFloat();
        float s = v.Mean(x);
        System.out.println("x=" + s);
        double a = v.cos(x);
        System.out.println("cos x=" + a);
        double q = v.tg(x);
        System.out.println("tg x=" + q);
        double w = v.ctg(x);
        System.out.println("ctg x=" + w);
        double e = v.Sqrt(x);
        System.out.println("sqrt x=" + e);
        int r = v.Round(x);
        System.out.println("round x=" + r);
        float t = v.Upsidedown(x);
        System.out.println("not x=" + t);
        float k = v.NotInt(x);
        System.out.println("not int x=" + k);
        float u = v.Int(x);
        System.out.println("int x=" + u);
        boolean i = v.WhatParity(x);
        System.out.println("parity x=" + i);
        int o = (int) v.Factorial((int) x);
        System.out.println("factorial x=" + o);
        float p = v.NSD(x, y);
        System.out.println("NSD x&y=" + p);
    }
}


class MathFun {
    static int sthow;

    MathFun() {

    }

    public static float Mean(float x) {
        return x;

    }

    public static double cos(float x) {
        double y = Math.cos(x);
        return y;
    }

    public static double tg(float x) {
        double y = Math.tan(x);
        return y;
    }

    public static double ctg(float x) {
        double y = Math.cos(x) / Math.sin(x);
        return y;
    }

    public static double Sqrt(float x) {
        double y = Math.sqrt(x);
        return y;
    }

    public static int Round(float x) {
        int y = Math.round(x);
        return y;
    }

    public static float Upsidedown(float x) {
        float y = 0 - x;
        return y;
    }

    public static float NotInt(float x) {
        int y = Math.round(x);
        float v = x - y;
        return v;
    }

    public static float Int(float x) {
        int y = Math.round(x);
        float v = x - y;
        float d = x - v;
        return d;
    }

    public static boolean WhatParity(float a) {
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static float Factorial(int x) {
        int f = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            f = f * i;
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static float NSD(float x, float y) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return y;
        }

        while (y != 0) {
            if (x > y) {
                x = x - y;
            } else {
                y = y - x;
            }

        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Очень много проблем с типами. Сильно не разбирался, но вот так работает.

Answer (score 1):

не хватает ещё одной `}` перед `public class Main`

либо в методе `NSD` у `else` убрать `{` если он не предполагался

Comment: XD, ладно без комментариев

Comment: @ПавелЕриков ответ то верный, шо минус то?))

Comment: Изначально был не очень полезным)) сейчас стал чуть полезней, но осадок остался от предыдущей версии